# mvc:resources Spring mapping not working

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to map any requests that come to `/views/node_modules/*` to `/resources/angular_resources/*` folder in my Spring project. How could I achieve this?

Currently I have `applicationContext.xml` file that looks the following way:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="fomoapp.domain, fomoapp.dao, fomoapp.service" />

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/node_modules/**" location="/resources/angular_resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Full `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
    classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>fomoapp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/fomoapp-config.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>fomoapp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/views/node_modules/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried the solution here: [Absolute path in <mvc:resources/> instead of path relative to mapping of spring servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184066/absolute-path-in-mvcresources-instead-of-path-relative-to-mapping-of-spring?rq=1)

But it does not work somehow.

Comment: can you provide the full web.xml file. As from this understanding your server starts with a default mapping of /views/node_modules/ which in this case is not not clear. How are trying to access the files.

Comment: Here it is: added full `web.xml`

Comment: Files are served fine from `resources` folder, but I need to map other requests (`views/node_modules`) to a folder inside of the `resources` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately solved it. The following thread really helped me: [Use of multiple "mvc:resources" tag in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208273/use-of-multiple-mvcresources-tag-in-spring-mvc).

So, I did the following:

1. Remove `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` from `applicationContext.xml` and add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` at the bottom instead
2. Remove `default` servlet stuff from `web.xml`

After doing this I was able to add additional mappings to `applicationContext.xml`. Here it is:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="fomoapp.domain, fomoapp.dao, fomoapp.service" />

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/node_modules/@angular/**" location="/resources/angular_resources/@angular/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/node_modules/rxjs/**" location="/resources/angular_resources/rxjs/" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: I was struggling with this and solved it using the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should map the static URLs to the Spring servlet, not the default servlet.
So your code should be,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fomoapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: No, these are working just fine actually and I get all the mappings right. I need a different mapping, a new one. Anyway, I tried what you are saying  and it is not working. Moreover, it breaks the mapping from resources to resources that is currently working.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep resources directory in Directory

- NetBeans: Web Pages
- Eclipse: webapps

File: dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/theme_name/" mapping="/resources/**"  cache-period="10000"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

File: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In JSP File

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/default.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use tomcat and jsp. You can create a web MVC configurations and register handler to /static/** route

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");

        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
}
```

Static file can then be accessed from `/static/{URL}`. Note that in my case I used jasper, tomcat and jstl and static resources were placed under *src/java/main/webapp*